# A question in studying Maximum-Minimum principle?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $ u $ be a continuous function on closed ball $ B[x,r_0] \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n, n = 2,3 $ and satisfy
\begin{equation*}
 \int_{B[x,r]} u(y) dy = 0, \forall r \leq r_0
\end{equation*}
How can we deduce that $ u(y) = 0, \forall y \in  B[x,r_0] $?

Comment: @ Thomas Sorry, i'll edit it.

Comment: I see. You can't. You can only conclude $u(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can't deduce that. For instance, you could have $u=r\sin\phi$ in polar coordinates for $n=2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n=1$,

$$2a\min\{u(y): x-a < y < x+a\} \le \int_{x-a}^{x+a}u(y)dy\, \le\, 2a\max\{u(y): x-a < y < x+a\}$$

If $u$ is continuous, ask yourself what this means for $a\rightarrow 0$ and how to generalize this to higher dimensions.